# Can I set the onTap later to a custom function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can I set onTap function later? Something like this:

```
ListTile tile = ListTile(title: Text("Hello!"));
tile.onTap = () => {print('Hello!');};
```

or something...?

Edit:

I want to change this:

```
ListTile createListTile(BuildContext context, String name) {
    ListTile tile;

    if (name == menuOptionsNames[0]) {
      tile = ListTile(
        title: Text(
          name,
          style: listTileTextStyle(),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()));
        },
      );
    } else if (name == menuOptionsNames[1]) {
      tile = ListTile(
        title: Text(
          menuOptionsNames[1],
          style: listTileTextStyle(),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Timetracker(menuOptionsNames[1])));
        },
      );
    } else if (name == menuOptionsNames[2]) {
      tile = ListTile(
        title: Text(
          menuOptionsNames[2],
          style: listTileTextStyle(),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Journal(menuOptionsNames[2])));
        },
      );
    }

    return tile;
  }
```

Into this:

```
  ListTile createListTile(BuildContext context, String name) {
    ListTile tile = ListTile(
      title: Text(
        name,
        style: listTileTextStyle(),
      ),
    );

    if (name == menuOptionsNames[0]) {
      tile.onTap = () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()));
      };
    } else if (name == menuOptionsNames[1]) {
      tile.onTap = () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Timetracker(menuOptionsNames[1])));
      };
    } else if (name == menuOptionsNames[2]) {
      tile.onTap = () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Journal(menuOptionsNames[2])));
      };
    }
return tile;
}
```

As you can see if I could set the onTap function later than when I create the ListTile object, I could change the behaviour of it based on a String. I could stop repeating the following code: ListTile(
title: Text(
name,
style: listTileTextStyle(),
),
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a local Variable Function() function and use it this way:

```
ListTile tile = ListTile(title: Text("Hello!"), onTap: () => function?.call());
function = () => {print('Hello!');};
```

You could also definde an object which holds the function:

```
class FunctionWrapper{
   Function() function;
}
```

After that, you can change that Function from everywhere:

```
ListTile tile = ListTile(title: Text("Hello!"), onTap: () => functionWrapper.function?.call());
functionWrapper.function = () => {print('Hello!');};
```

The normal way to do this is the definition of a mutable local variable but if you can't do that for any reason, you can use the FunctionWrapper instead.

EDIT:

In your case you can just define a `Function() function` variable at the begin of your method and pass this function at the end to your ListTile:

```
Function() function;
if (name == menuOptionsNames[0]) {
      function = () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()));
      };
    } else if (name == menuOptionsNames[1]) {
      function = () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Timetracker(menuOptionsNames[1])));
      };
    } else if (name == menuOptionsNames[2]) {
      function = () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Journal(menuOptionsNames[2])));
      };
    }

return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        name,
        style: listTileTextStyle(),
      ),
      onTap: function,
    );
```

Or even better:

```
Function() function;
    if (name == menuOptionsNames[0] || name == menuOptionsNames[1] || name == menuOptionsNames[2]) {
         Function(BuildContext) builder;
         if(name == menuOptionsNames[0])
           builder = (context) => FirstPage();
         else if (name == menuOptionsNames[1]) {
             builder = (context) => Timetracker(menuOptionsNames[1]);
         else
             builder = (context) => Journal(menuOptionsNames[2]);

         function = () =>
             Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: builder);
    }
    
    return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            name,
            style: listTileTextStyle(),
          ),
          onTap: function,
        );
```

Comment: I added some additional info to the question

Comment: Nice, works great. Thanks! Any chance to simplify this part: builder: (context) => Timetracker(menuOptionsNames[1])));? I mean the class I give to it... Somehow if I could tell the class name as a String and it would the constructor of that class. Then I could get rid much more code (Navigator.pop... most part of Navigator.push... are repeated). But anyway, thanks for simplifying the code I asked in the question!

Comment: My approach for your is simply write one public method for getting an object by passing the String to this method. So you only have to write the same thing once.

Answer (score 0):

You should have variable to indicate that user can tap in ontap event
for e.g.

```
bool canTap = false;
```

and pre-set ontap attribute normally but check before do something when tap

```
onTap: () => { if (capTap) {print('Hello!');}};
```

then use

```
 setState({ canTap = true/false });
```

to change state

Comment: I added some additional info to the question